# Selecting a Build Server

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, build

I'm planning to setup my own build server. I'm primary building C#, C/C++ and Java projects. I would also like my build server to run some external programs/scripts such as my unit tests, code static analysis and doxygen.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Hudson Continuous-Integration](http://hudson-ci.org/) software.

Comment: This one looks very interesting. I think I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

We're using [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). It's easy to configure, user friendly, has convenient plug-ins for notifications on build events, you can install multiple build workers, define any build engine (.net, java...), it can output artifacts, it can trigger automatically on check-in, it can execute any custom build script etc, etc... and most of all - it's free (for up to 20 configurations).

We've looked far and wide, and we found this to be the best...

Comment: My team considered TeamCity too but stuck with CruiseControl.NET (CCNET) since CCNET offers a command line runner (ccnet.exe) which allows new developers and testers to download a pre-packaged build-script and simply run it - without needing to set up their own servers or configure it. Would you know if TeamCity allows a similar command-line runner?

Answer (score 0):

Hardware: Discs. Quite some, or a decent SSD. A lot of the stuff you do will be disc based from the compiler side. Not talking about the get latest version (alone), but for example a c++ compiler generates QUITE a number of interim files in the build process. A decent fast subsystem can make a recognizable difference. Especially fi this is not for you but for some colleagues as well, sotit may run a lot concurrently.

Well, enough RAM and a modern multi core CPU go without saying.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) and [Bitten](http://bitten.edgewall.org/), which worked quite well. I used it for C# and Python projects.

I have it building, creating docs and running unit tests. Currently I'm investigating running dotCover for test coverage, which shouldn't be too difficult, because bitten basically allows you to call any shell command you need.

Actually, I usually run the build system on an old (not-so-fast) system - it doesn't need to be very quick for me. I like to have developers behind the fast machines ;-)